# Grid layout tiny on iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, css

I assume this has to do with the retina display and thus everything is twice as small as it should be on the iPhone.

This is the site I'm working on: http://share-the-secret.com/

If you resize the site horizontally to two grid block, that's how it is supposed to look on the iPhone. Currently on the iPhone you see the four grid layout.

I do not want to use media queries to give a custom size for all the elements on the iPhone.

Is there an easier fix for this?

Thanks!

Comment: When I visit on my iPhone 5, I get a single column of blocks. I didn't see you using the viewport meta tag before, but it looks like you are using it now?  That tag is what I was going to suggest.

Comment: Yup. Just figured it out 2 mins ago haha

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution!

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```